# Modifiying source code of an application

Tags: linux, debian

I'm doing a project where i need to change or add some functionality on an Debian based application. I've downloaded the source code but problem is they all have `.rpm` as extension. Anyone know what do I need to do to modify it and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why a "Debian-based" application would have its source code in RPM format. How are you downloading the source code? Usually on Debian you can do it with:

```
# apt-get source <package_name>
```

Assuming the package is in the repos, of course. If you mean you downloaded the source code as a source RPM from, say, a project's website, you can always install `rpm2cpio` on your Debian machine and extract the package:

```
# apt-get install rpm2cpio
# mkdir extracted_source_package
# mv blah.rpm extracted_source_package
# cd extracted_source_package
# rpm2cpio blah.rpm | cpio --extract --make-directories --verbose
```

**Reference**

- [How to Use an [sic] Source RPM](http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/internal/native/using-srpm.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I'm a newbie in linux and i've sayed an "Debian-based" cause that's why someone told me how it was made but maybe he was wrong then. The application in question is the Endian FireWall so i don't know on which system is it.  and i've dowloaded the package from the endian website. And thank you for the reference i think i will need it a lot

Comment: i've done the command you've given but where did the file goes??

Comment: @user52356 The file should be moved to the directory you created in the second step (which I've called `extracted_source_package` in this example).

Comment: @user52356s Please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted if it helped solve your problem. This way people browsing the forum will know that this problem has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change **functionality** you'll need to download the **source code** (a version control repository) rather than the installable (RPM file). The RPM file usually contains only a compiled (binary) version of the software, and modifying that is usually infeasible.

Some packages have a `*-source.rpm` file which you can use to get the source code, but usually you'll have to go to the home page of the application to get the source code repository.

As for how to modify the package, that is an enormously broad question. Essentially it depends on the nature and complexity of the change, which languages are involved, and whether the code is even open source (which it usually is if it's available as an RPM (plus very likely a host of other factors). It might be more useful to ask a more specific question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually the project i'm in involve adding somme functionnality to the endian firewall or creating something similar to it. So can you advice me where to start with? cause i'm a bit new with linux